# Java 8 Double function reference?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, method-reference

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Dependency{      
   public Dependency reverse() { ... } // returns this Dependency after some reverse OP

   public int doSomething(int param) { ... }

}
```

Can I use it like this:

```
Optional<Integer> opt = ...
Dependency dep = new Dependency();

opt.map(dep::reverse::doSomething);
```

This would be quite clean, but is it possible? To apply a transformation (`reverse`) to `Dependency` and then apply the `doSomething` method?

Comment: *"Can I use it like this"* - no, this wont compile. Double-reference is not a thing. Maybe you intend to do two `map` calls. `opt.map(...).map(...)`. Not exactly sure though what you are attempting to do here. It would help if you could show a working code snippet, even if it is not as elegant as you would like it to be. Just to understand your scenario.

Comment: You say (in the code comment) that `reverse()` modifies the `Dependency` instance? Then, why not change the declaration to `Dependency dep = new Dependency().reverse();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, seems that `reverse()` won't be consuming the `Integer`, so you could simply do:

```
opt.map(dep.reverse()::doSomething);
```